# While background div with video finishes loading, show entire div with loading

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, html5-video

I have a div that has a background video whos size is roughly 6mb. I want to show the entire page until that video finishes loading.

I've seen in plenty websites, specially the ones of movies (recent ones) they have background video, and before they show the page, there's like a loading screen.

How can I achieve this? I've been searching around but so far, no luck. Is there a specific name for this technique if you can call it like that?

Comment: how you are loading video .. you are using latest html5 video tag???

Comment: Yes, I'm using the html5 `<video</video>` tag.

Answer (score 0):

You can use jquery to achieve this like follows:

```
  $(window).load(function() {
    $('PUT_ID_OF_VIDEO_CONTAINER_HERE').hide();
  });
```

Comment: And how will i know the video is loaded and thus show it back again?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using the callback on jQuery load() like this >>>

```
<div id=videoHolder></div>
<div id=loadrHolder></div>
<script>
$( document ).ready(function() {
$('#videoHolder').hide();
$('#videoHolder').load( "myVideo.mp4", function() {
    $('#videoHolder').show();
    $('#loadrHolder').hide();
});
});
</script
```

Comment: This makes the page go in an infinite loop until it crashes.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a library like jquery.videoBG (http://syddev.com/jquery.videoBG/) to show the video, I think you could modify the code to show your page when the video has been loaded.

HTML:

```
<body>
    <div id="dvLoading">Loading...</div>
    <div id="dvContent" style="display:none"></div>
</body>
```

Javascript in library:

```
$video.bind('canplaythrough',function() {
    $('#dvLoading').hide();
    $('#dvContent').show();
});
```

You can find a listing of the events for the video element here: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_av_dom.asp